# When building boost.python why do some files get 'python' in the name and others get 'python3'?

Tags: python, c++, boost, python-extensions

For example, if I run the following command:

```
bjam --toolset=msvc-14.0 address-model=64 --with-python python-debugging=off threading=multi variant=debug toolset=msvc-14.0 link=static --stagedir=stage\x64-static-python35 stage
```

2 files are produced:

- libboost_python-vc140-mt-gd-1_62.lib
- libboost_python3-vc140-mt-gd-1_62.lib

Why does one have 'python' in the name and the other 'python3'?

Comment: This is because Python has two variants `2.7.x`  and `3.5.x` with slightly different syntax amongst other kinks and the build process is producing libraries for both versions. For more details visit [Python2orPython3](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3)

Comment: I configured bjam to use python3.4 on my system (via the user-config.jam file). Why would it use python 2.7.x?